# Как подсчитать li списки и вывести нумерацию?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем доброго времени суток!
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать вывод такого списка, чтобы рядом где нумерация выводилось еще сколько осталось списков ниже, а последний список выводил не номер списка, а слово например "Готово".

Сделал нумерацию через css, но это немного не то.
[image: Пример вывода нумерации]

Вот код как я вывожу сейчас:

```css
ol li {
  display: flex;
  padding: 40px 0 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  position: relative;
  counter-increment: my-awesome-counter;
  border-bottom: 2px dashed #e6e6e6;
}

ol li::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 7px;
  left: 0;
  content: "Шаг" " " counter(my-awesome-counter);
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: brown;
}

ol li:last-child::after {
  content: "Готово!";
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Пример списка</li>
  <li>Пример списка</li>
  <li>Пример списка</li>
  <li>Пример списка</li>
  <li>Пример списка</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49317126/css-how-to-count-total-number-of-pages/49317785

Comment: @splash58 продублируйте ответ на RuSO

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот решение с помощью JS

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  list('#list li')
})


const list = selector => {
  const listItems = document.querySelectorAll(selector) // достаем все нужные ДОМ узлы

  listItems.forEach((item, index) => { // перебераем каждый елемент и вставляем в него нужный спан с каунтером
    let span = document.createElement('span')
    span.classList.add('counter')
    span.innerHTML = `Шаг ${index + 1} из ${listItems.length}` // тут текст каунтера
    item.append(span)
  })

  const lastItem = document.querySelectorAll('#list li')[listItems.length - 1] // последний елемент списка 
  lastItem.lastChild.innerHTML = 'Готово'
}
```

```css
ol li {
  display: flex;
  padding: 40px 0 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  position: relative;
  counter-increment: my-awesome-counter;
  border-bottom: 2px dashed #e6e6e6;
}

ol li .counter {
  position: absolute;
  top: 7px;
  left: 0;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: brown;
}
```

```html
<ol id="list">
  <li>Пример списка</li>
  <li>Пример списка</li>
  <li>Пример списка</li>
  <li>Пример списка</li>
  <li>Пример списка</li>
</ol>
```